# Django WebRTC TURN/STUN/ICE Server

Tags: django, webrtc, django-channels

So I have a basic question about WebRTC with Python Django.

Maybe I start at the beginning:

So is it possible that Python Django can serve as a Server for WebRTC? I think in generell it shouldn't be **that** hard, because how I saw the WebRTC client only needs a Websocket connection. I hope anybody can help me with that. Btw. I use Django Channels, so I think it is possible to build this connection, but **how**? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible but I do not recommend!

Instead, there are some WebRTC media servers like `Jitsi`, `AntMedia` and `Janus`. I used the last one on one of our project with Django.

Checkout microservices achitecture and find a way to combine your project with `Django` (for Authentication, Authorization and other processes) + `WebRTC Media Server` + `Frontend` and/or `Mobile App`. May Frontend could be in same code base with Django, up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess they're not recommending it above because it gets complicated very quickly implementing WebRTC video calls on your own with cross-browser support (Safari, especially). Using existing video APIs that have done that work for you can be a great option for a lot of companies to avoid all the edge cases that affect video quality. Daily, Agora, Twilio are all video API options that can handle this work for you.